# Couldn't Convert jTextfield string into float value..... Giving number format exception

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtextfield, numberformatexception

Im experiencing a problem in parsing `jTextfield` into `float` value so i can perform operation but its giving number format exception

Here is the Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
```

and this is what im doing

```
float T1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_T1_f.getText());
```

Comment: Probably what you're doing is  putting that code in your constructor or your initialization method. That won't yield the result you're expecting. Instead, that code should be in some listener call back like an `actionPerformed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check on the *text* value like this:

```
String text = txt_T1_f.getText();
if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
    float T1 = Float.parseFloat(text);
}
```

Comment: Ravi Longia, if you are happy with one of the questions, you should mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before converting to float, check your string is not empty and not null. You are getting excepting since your string is empty.

use

```
  if(txt_T1_f.getText()!=null && !txt_T1_f.getText().isEmpty())
  float T1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_T1_f.getText());
```

Comment: For length()!=0 there is a method isEmpty(). And I'd rather create a variable instead of calling txt_T1_f.getText() 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your string to find out is it a float at all?
try this:

```
    String regex="^([+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)$";
    String input = txt_T1_f.getText();
    float T1 ;
    if(Pattern.matches(regex, input)){
        T1 = Float.valueOf(input);
    }
```